# How to Show Http Header manager in request in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I want to display HTTP Header manager which are used for API, I have added JSR223 PostProcessor for displaying request parameter which is working fine, now same I want to display Http Header manager used for API.
[image]

Comment: I trust you want to view the HTTP request headers sent along with the HTTP Requests. [Configuration elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#config_elements) , [Logical Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers) etc are not displayed through the View result tree.

Comment: is there any way to display http header manager along with HTTP request

Comment: Why do you want to display `Header Manager` when all the information (headers) from the `Header Manager` are available through the **Request--> Request Headers** panel?

Answer (score 0):

The [Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) lets you add or override HTTP request headers. You can view the headers sent with the requests through the view result tree.

Select the request from the view result tree--> Request--> Request Headers
[image]

If you wish to see the headers in a table format select the HTTP button at the bottom of the window.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, But I want to show the Header request in View result tree For Eg, "HTTP Request Content-Type:Application/Json" in request

Comment: `Content-Type: Application/Json` will be available in the HTTP request header when you set the header through the `Header Manager`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same JSR223 PostProcessor for displaying request and response headers, for example hers is how you can print them to the [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging):

```
log.info('Request headers: ' + System.getProperty('line.separator') + prev.getRequestHeaders())

log.info('Response headers: ' + System.getProperty('line.separator') + prev.getResponseHeaders())
```

in the above code `prev` stands for [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance, see JavaDoc for more information on all methods and fields and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more details on this and other JMeter API shorthands avaiable for hte JSR223 Test Elements.

Also View Results Tree listener does already have headers information stored, just click `Request -> Request Headers` and/or `Response data -> Response Headers`

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Dmitri for your reply, Actually I wanted to show Http Header Maager in Request only as I am showing request data for Eg. Login:POST https://apigateway.erosnow.com/api/v1/auth/users/login POST data :{"Email":"xyz@gmail.com", "password":"xyz"} now along with with the value of HTTP header manager should also be displayed. in request sample so that it can view in view result tree

Comment: `prev.setSampleLabel(prev.getSampleLabel() + ' ' + prev.getRequestHeaders())`

Comment: Thank you very much Dmitri Again, You always help me in all kind of problems, This also has solved my Problem. Thank you very much once again